# What do we call the light disturbance around a lamp?

Tags: nouns

When a lamp or other luminous object is very bright, we cannot see clearly the things close to it. What we see is a whitish region that surrounds it. What do we call this? (Is it a perception or a phenomenon?)

[image: a very bright lamp]

This picture features a lamp in the centre; half the image consists of the white region surrounding the lamp.

Comment: I'd call it _glare_. Or since it's surrounding the light, it could be a _halo_.

Comment: This questions belongs on [physics.se]. Suggesting migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are observing is **glare** that forms a **halo** around the lamp.

It is caused by the scattering (i.e. dispersal) of the rays of light. This partly results from the light emitted from the bulb being scattered as it interacts with the air molecules through which it passes before it reaches the observer's eye, and partly from the interaction of the light with the structures of the eye itself.

Specifically, the lens of the eye scatters some of the light. (This happens particularly in an older person whose lenses may be developing cataracts, i.e. degradation of the lens structure through the accumulation of opaque or reflective proteins, pigments etc.)

There is also some internal reflection in the lens which can cause the appearance of ghost images in the eye, though that is not evident in the image you posted.

Comment: Having a fox as a 'trusted user' brings the word 'henhouse' to mind.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Yes, it's the ideal combination!